# Can some Survival Models "Dominate" other Survival Models?

Tags: regression, survival, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I recently heard an interesting interpretation of Survival Models : A "standard" Survival Analysis problem (e.g. where at the end of the study, observations can either be "Censored" or experience the "Event") can correspond to a Markov Chain with 3 States (Healthy = First State, Event = Second State, Censored = Third State) in which all observations begin in the "First State" and by the end of the study (if they have not transitioned already) must transition to either the "Second State" or the "Third State". In the traditional sense, the "Second State" and the "Third State" are usually considered to be as "Absorbing States" - this means that when an individual is "censored" or experiences the "event" - they can not transition back to being "healthy".

With this interpretation in mind, I was trying to learn more about the following two types of Survival Models:

- Competing Risk Models
- Multi-State Models

In Competing Risk Models, individuals can now transition to "n" number of states (instead of only 2 states) - for example, the "event of interest" might be "diagnosis of asthma" , but a "competing" event might be " diagnosis of gout". As in the traditional case, these "n" states (along with the "censoring state") are still considered to be "absorbing" states.

In Multi-State Models, individuals can now transition to "n" number of states, but some of these "n" states do not necessarily need to be "absorbing states". For instance, suppose there are 3 states (Healthy, Sick, Dead) - logically speaking, Dead" can be considered as an "absorbing state", but in individuals might now be allowed to freely transition between the "Healthy" and "Sick" states multiple times throughout the study.

This leads me to my question: At a first glance, it would appear as though everything that can be accomplished using the Competing Risk Model can also be accomplished using the Multi-State Model ... but not everything that can be accomplished using the Multi-State Model can also be accomplished using the Competing Risk Model. **Does this mean that the Multi-State Model "dominates" the Competing Risk Model and can be considered as a "superior" model?**

My guess is that this is probably not the case, and the Competing Risk Model might still have advantageous properties when compared to the Multi-State Model (e.g. less computationally expensive to estimate model parameters, "better" statistical properties of estimates (e.g. stronger consistency, asymptotic normality), might require less data to implement, etc.) - but I am not sure about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a subset issue, not a "superiority" issue. Do you think that multivariate multiple  regression is "superior" to simple linear regression?

A competing-risk model is just a particular form of multi-state model. The essential modeling approach is the same for both: it's a matter of the states between which the modeler allows transitions. For Cox regression, both can be fit by the same `coxph()` function once transition models are specified.

See the R [Multi-state models and competing risks vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf). As Section 3 puts it:

> The analysis of multi-state data has four key steps. In order of importance: 1. Draw a box and arrow figure describing the model...Step 1 is key to the entire endeavor.

If your box-and-arrow figure has multiple states from which no further transitions are possible, those are competing risks. Otherwise you have a different multi-state model. Neither is "superior" or "inferior," except insofar as one might be more suitable for a particular task.

Comment: @ EdM : Thank you for your answer! In this case, I was wondering - it seems like Multi State Models can do everything that Competing Risk Models can do. This being said, are there any types of problems where Competing Risk Models present any significant advantages compared to Multi State Models? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob I don't know of any extension of the Fine-Gray approach to competing risks that handles other multi-state model types. See the linked vignette for details. Fine-Gray turns "the multi-state problem into a collection of two-state ones." That might just be my ignorance, however. Whether having the Fine-Gray alternative is an "advantage" of competing risk models over other multi-state models is another question; I still have a hard time getting my head around Fine-Gray.